# Azure VNet Peering Deny Assignment

Tags: azure, azure-networking

Networking is not my specialty, but am trying to add Vnet peering between SQL database and Azure Databricks, so that the Databricks clusters have their IP Addresses whitelisted (If you know a better solution, please enlighten me!).

However, when adding peering between each resources's Vnet, I am unable to do so on the Databricks side because of a read-only Deny Assignment. I am an administrator on all resources, but seem to be locked from making any changes to remove the deny assignment so the Vnet peering can take place.

Is there any workarounds on either end here?

Answer (score 1):

If you have deployed DataBricks to it's own vNet then peering this is not supported, see [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/cloud-configurations/azure/vnet-peering).

> VNet peering is not supported when you deploy an Azure Databricks
> workspace to your own virtual network (also known as VNet injection).